# Python NameError issue

Tags: python-3.x, list, insert, nameerror

I have an issue with my code saying that I have a `NameError` and my name is not defined. Although from what I know my name is defined.

```
# Create UAS database list that was displayed in the file
uas_Stock = [["CS116",1],["CS117",1],["CS118",1],["CS119",1],["CS120",1]]

# Ask user to select which UAV they want to check out.
uas_out = str(input("Which UAV would you like to checkout? "))

# Append stock list to show UAS is checked out
if uas_out == CS116:
    list.insert(0,1, "0")
elif uas_out == CS117:
    list.insert(1,1, "0")
elif uas_out == CS118:
    list.insert(2,1, "0")
elif uas_out == CS119:
    list.insert(3,1, "0")
else:
    list.insert(4,1, "0")
```

I expect the result to take the uas_out value and run through the if/else statement and execute whichever one it says. Then that will append the list to give the value of the certain list 0 instead of 1.

The error I am getting when I input a value for uas_out is:

```
NameError: name '(whatever uas_out is/CS116/117/118/119/120)' is not defined.
```

Answer (score 1):

CS116 et al are strings, not variables, and they need to be surrounded by quotes:

```
if uas_out == 'CS116':
    list.insert(0,1, "0")
elif uas_out == 'CS117':
    list.insert(1,1, "0")
elif uas_out == 'CS118':
    list.insert(2,1, "0")
elif uas_out == 'CS119':
    list.insert(3,1, "0")
else:
    list.insert(4,1, "0")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been looking at this for too long. I think that is why I didn't see how simple it was.